# How do you sort a STL list without mutating the original?

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have something like this below:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <list> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    list<int> mylist{ 1, 5, 3, 2, 4 }; 

    // sort
    mylist.sort(); 

    // printing the list after sort 
    for (auto it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it) 
        cout << ' ' << *it; 
    return 0; 
}
```

However, if I do that, the original list is permanently changed. I know there are a lot of ways to do it. But specifically I want to know how I can sort it without making a copy of the original list explicitly. I want to do it with a function that is passed by value so that changes will be temporary.

Comment: The only way is to make a copy of the list. Whether it's an explicit copy or in any way hidden behind a layer of abstraction, it's still a copy.

Comment: @Fuzzy Stussy And what is the problem?! Pass the list by value to your function.

Comment: Passing by value is a copy. You can't have two lists without a copy, that's just not possible.

Comment: sorting without making a copy, but keeping the original unmodified ? how should that be possible? Why don't you want to make a copy and keep the original unmodified at the same time?

Comment: Implement a basic sorting algorithm yourself that uses `std::swap` to rearrange the values in the list, without changing the list itself.

Comment: You want to rearrange the elements without rearranging the elements?

Comment: You could make some kind of flat copy of your list elements - storing iterators to all nodes of the list in a `std::vector<std::list<int>::iterator>`. As long as you don't erase anything in the `std::list`, the iterators remain valid. With the appropriate custom predicate, you can sort the `std::vector`, and this will not effect the list itself.

Comment: I know that in C++ everything is passed by the value to the calling function. How can I use that logic to sort the list without touching the original list?

Comment: it is not clear what problem you are facing, instead of entering more discussions, I just posted "the obvious" as answer. Still, out of curiosity, I would be interested in what is your "problem"

Comment: By definition, sorting a list changes the list, since it reorders elements.    If you want to keep the original list, then it is necessary create a copy before sorting - and sort either the original or the copy (not both).    You can't have your cake (a sorted list) and eat it to (have the unsorted version without creating a copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to do it with a function that is passed by value so that changes will be temporary.

Sure you can do that:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <list> 
using namespace std; 

void foo(list<int> l) {   // pass by copy !
    l.sort();
    // printing the list after sort 
    for (auto it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it) 
        cout << ' ' << *it; 
}


int main() 
{ 
    list<int> mylist{ 1, 5, 3, 2, 4 }; 

    // sort
    foo(mylist);     


    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. So you can actually pass the entire list as an argument. Thanks!

Comment: Although this doesn't meet the requirement of not copying the list.   Passing a list by value works by passing a copy.

Comment: @Peter original question was changed from "without making a copy of the original list"  to "without making a copy of the original list explicitly". Not sure what that is supposed to mean though

Comment: Maybe the OP is looking for an equivalent to LINQ's [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8) extension method. The function should in C++return  something like a list of reference wrappers, or rather an iterator so that one can do deferred execution...

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica actually I wasnt sure what OP is looking for, the question is a bit unclear and instead of discussing I decided to simply post that. Their comment suggests that there was just a misunderstanding about passing a list as parameter

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Basically I didn't want to make an actual copy by myself but to make a copy with passing by value. That way the original remains untouched. @idclev463035818 showed me exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Re-arrange elements of a list without changing the list itself reminds me to something what I would call a proxy.

In this case, a `std::vector` of list iterators could be used as proxy. I would consider a `std::vector` as cache friendly (contiguous storage of contents) which may be an additional advantage concerning the performance of sorting.

The proxy vector is sorted with a custom predicate which considers the contents at iterators.

A sample:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  using listInt = std::list<int>;
  listInt myList{ 1, 5, 3, 2, 4 };
  // proxy for sorted access
  { std::vector<listInt::iterator> proxy;
    proxy.reserve(myList.size());
    for (listInt::iterator iter = myList.begin();
      iter != myList.end(); ++iter) {
      proxy.push_back(iter);
    }
    // sort proxy:
    std::sort(proxy.begin(), proxy.end(),
      [](listInt::iterator iter1, listInt::iterator iter2)
      {
        return *iter1 < *iter2;
      });
    // show proxy result
    for (listInt::iterator iter : proxy) {
      std::cout << ' ' << *iter;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
  std::cout << "The list (still in original order):\n";
  for (int value : myList) {
    std::cout << ' ' << value;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
 1 2 3 4 5
The list (still in original order):
 1 5 3 2 4
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60903769deae5cfe)

Please note, as long as none of the list elements is deleted the list iterators are stable. ([Get pointer to node in std::list or std::forward_list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21941946/7478597))

It might be questionable whether to store iterators instead of the values (which are plain `int`) is an advantage in any way. However, the size of iterator probably won't change if the list would contain elements of a "heavier" type where a deep copy would  have a significant impact or even prohibited.

---

Googling a bit afterwards, I found this:

[SO: Sort by proxy (or: sort one container by the contents of another) in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3398928/7478597)

which might be related (IMHO).